# Usage of "context"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I wrote:

> Moreover, **the context in which desired items can present/appear/placed** is specified using variables called context variables.

I mean on a web page , the desired items (elements) can be specified using some conditions over the place they can appear (let's call it context). Does the sentence above is in accord with this interpretation? Does items can *place/appear/present* in a context?

How about the following options:

- Moreover, **the context of desired items** can be specified using variables called context variables (First, I am doubtful about "the", Second,  I don't think *context* is a part or property of *desired items*).
- Moreover, **the context for desired items** can be specified using variables called context variables (It could be better, but maybe needs more description like the first sentence with *in which*).

Comment: Using ***present*** here is inappropriate (it's essentially a "medical" usage, in that *patients* and *symptoms* often "present" = ***show up, become apparent***). Most common would be ***can appear*** (where the "desired items" are doing the appearing), but you need the passive form ***can be placed*** if the placement is being done by some unspecified programmer.

Comment: @fu what about the other options?

Comment: Aside from the "of vs. for" issue, "context" has a broad meaning. Unless you're specifically defining what you mean by context earlier, either of your definitions is potentially confusing to a user reading the instructions.